# Firebase Realtime database return wrong value in the second time returned snapshot

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am reading user profile from database, but the first time I read, it returns the right value (full attributes of a user object), but the second time it fires, it returns only 1 attribute (other attributes is null). this is my code

```
 if (mProfileValueEvent != null) mProfileRef.removeEventListener(mProfileValueEvent);

        mProfileValueEvent = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (getFirebaseUser() != null) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        final User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        Log.d("RRRRRRRR1",dataSnapshot+"");

                        if (user != null) {

                            Log.d("RRRRRRRR2",user.getName()+"");

                            tv_name.setText(user.getName());
                            tv_email.setText(user.getEmail());
                            tv_status.setText(user.getStatus());

                            setAvatarToView(user.getThumbAvatarUrl(), user.getName(), civ_avatar);

                            setMyGlobalProfile(user);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        mProfileRef.addValueEventListener(mProfileValueEvent);
```

this is the log cat :

```
/RRRRRRRR1: DataSnapshot { key = kk44p2XW97OIxAudLwekOZwZM7B2, value = {password=12345678, status="pla pla", verified=true, userId=kk44p2XW97OIxAudLwekOZwZM7B2, dateofbirth=18/08/2003, lastSeen=1575100843974, email="email@gmail.com", name=Mẫn Mẫn, gender=Nữ, joinedDate=18/08/2019} }
/RRRRRRRR2: Mẫn Mẫn

/RRRRRRRR1: DataSnapshot { key = kk44p2XW97OIxAudLwekOZwZM7B2, value = {lastSeen=-1} }
2019-11-30 15:05:22.377 24224-24224/com.example.tranquoctrungcntt.uchat D/RRRRRRRR2: null
```

version of library

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
```

**THIS IS THE COMPLETE CODE I USE TO READ THE USER PROFILE**

***Check connection to know user online or offline***

```
 mDatabaseConnectionValueEvent = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                boolean isConnected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

                if (isConnected) {

                    final DatabaseReference ACTIVE_REF = 
                               ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_USERS).child(getMyUID());

                    Map<String, Object> mapOnline = new HashMap<>();

                   mapOnline.put(kLastSeen, -1);

                   ACTIVE_REF.updateChildren(mapOnline);

                } else {

                 final DatabaseReference ACTIVE_REF = 
                           ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_USERS).child(getMyUID());

                 Map<String, Object> mapOffline = new HashMap<>();

                 mapOffline.put(kLastSeen, getCurrentTimeInMilies());

                 ACTIVE_REF.updateChildren(mapOffline);

               }

                 updateDatabaseConnectionStatus(isConnected);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        CONNECT_REF.addValueEventListener(mDatabaseConnectionValueEvent);
```

***Then, I read user profile like this : ***

```
        mProfileValueEvent = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (getFirebaseUser() != null) {

                    final User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    //should set up UI, but the snapshot contains only one key 
                    // "lastSeen"


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        mProfileRef.addValueEventListener(mProfileValueEvent);
```

**NOTE: This issue only happens when app first launch. After the first launch, it works fine (return enough data, I think because the data is cached)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase client always fires with the complete snapshot of the data at a location. So if you get this output:

> DataSnapshot { key = kk44p2XW97OIxAudLwekOZwZM7B2, value = {lastSeen=-1} }

There is some code that writes to `kk44p2XW97OIxAudLwekOZwZM7B2` with just a `lastSeen` value. You might want to check your code for calls to `setValue()`, as that would explain why the previous data under `kk44p2XW97OIxAudLwekOZwZM7B2` disappeared in that second snapshot.

Comment: I had some code write only ```setValue()``` like you said, but how to make it return a complete user profile, not just ```lastSeen``` attribute.

Comment: "I had some code write only setValue() like you said" The problem is in that code, as it seems to replace all data that you instead want to keep. You'll want to call `setValue` on a lower level, or call `updateChildren()` to update some properties without replacing the existing data.

Comment: I did ```updateChildren()```, but it does not work, still return just ```lastSeen```  This is my code ```final DatabaseReference ACTIVE_REF = ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_USERS).child(getMyUID());

            Map<String, Object> mapOnline = new HashMap<>();

            mapOnline.put(kLastSeen, -1);

            ACTIVE_REF.updateChildren(mapOnline);
```

Comment: That seems unusual. Can you create a minimal, standalone piece of code that I can easily run to reproduce the problem?